# Problems reading keys from properties file java

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a properties file that is used to control specific variables within my application. All but one of the keys I am using work perfectly fine as the application has been working.

The structure of the ini file is:

```
JDBC_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL=localhost/tempTables
EmailList=foo@bar.com
sender=foo_bar@tempfoo.com
host=<sanitised>
port=25
USER=root
PASS=Fo0b4R
path=C:/Users/foo/Desktop/profile_admin_
logLevel=2
TimerControl=2
```

The specific key I am having issues with is "logLevel". This is to be read as a string (using the Properties Class) and then parsed to an int. The key "port" follows this suit fine so I'm wondering if it is the keyname, or whether there is a limit to the number of keys.

Each key is read as follows:

```
FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream("config.ini");
Properties config = new Properties(System.getProperties());
config.load(propFile);
String level = config.getProperty("logLevel");
System.out.println("Purely for testing. Key \"logLevel\" is :"+level);
int levelLogger = Integer.parseInt(level);
System.out.println("Parsed to integer, printed for integrity: "+levelLogger);
//output
Purely for testing. Key "logLevel" is : null
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: nu;;
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at package.myClass.main(myClass.java:63)
```

Comment: isn't there any non-printing character after `2`?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj How do you mean?

Comment: Try to print `level.length()`. If it's higher than 1, you get some characters there you don't see

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I get a NullPointerException

Comment: It looks like property was not loaded at all. Are you sure you are opening right file? Is path correct?

Comment: @Fazovsky You hit the nail on the head. I made one of those beginner mistakes you just want to facepalm at.

Comment: This is not an 'ini' file, it is a Properties file. Enough confusion is enough already.

Comment: @EJP My apologies, I hadn't read into the Properties class correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was my own fault. Because I am using the current working directory for my ini, I had forgotten to move `config.ini` to the /bin folder (I am executing this application from CMD.